# unable to access env variables in app bootstrap

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use Slack to post my debug messages to. i have followed some exmaple code and have this in my app.php file

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function ($monolog) {
$monolog->pushHandler($chromeHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\ChromePHPHandler());
$chromeHandler->setFormatter(new \Monolog\Formatter\ChromePHPFormatter());

$slackHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\SlackHandler('xoxp-dasdasdzxczxcasdasdasdas', '#general');
$slackHandler->setLevel(\Monolog\Logger::INFO);
$slackHandler->setFormatter(new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter());
$monolog->pushHandler($slackHandler);

});
```

which works and send mesages to slack using the following command

```
  Log::info('thing to log');
```

I want to only send debug messages to slack if I am on a local machine.

I have tried reading in the the APP_ENV variable using env() but it is not returning anything.

I can access it using the same code in the controller. THerefore I assume it has not been loaded in the app.php file when I am trying to get it.

is there a better place to add the slack code, or anther way to detect the env variable?

Comment: You haven't acess to env variables at app.php. You should try to configureMonolog at your AppServiceProvider

Comment: That works thanks!